# Is there any published stats for public NTP servers

Tags: metrics, ntp

Public NTP servers metrics and statistics are valuable source of data, I couldn't find any published stats for public NTP servers such as:

```
time.windows.com
time.nist.gov
pool.ntp.org
```

The data can be used to find a good estimate of total number of machines world-wide currently online. In addition to many more insights.

Is there any policy prevents publishing the stats?

Remark: As programmer want to perform data analysis on public NTP servers stats, I assume this is valid question for SO. If not, then suggest alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NTP Pool system is decentralized and doesn't keep statistics like this. A napkin-math estimate would be that the NTP Pool servers do millions of queries per second in aggregate.

How clients behave varies wildly; I don't think you can infer anything else than "lots of clients as asking about the time" from that.

Comment: Found from your site that you are `timekeeper` at ntp.org :) , but since each client do dns request while asking for time, if dns logs maintained wouldn't that be useful for stats?! Maybe ntp.org doesn't, but what about the other two I mentioned? MS love to log everything, so I doubt that nothing get maintained, also if nothing logged in ntp.org, how its possible to prevent attacks such DDOS?